# Allocating zero capacity ByteBuffer

Tags: java, nio, bytebuffer

Can anybody please tell me what are those possible purposes of allocating zero-length buffer?

```
ByteBuffer.allocate(0); // no IllegalArgumentException
```

Why the one who designed the API did this?

**Thanks for comments and answers.**

I hope there will be an update like this. :)

```java
public abstract class ByteBuffer
    extends Buffer
    implements Comparable<ByteBuffer> {

    public static final ByteBuffer VOID = allocate(0);
}
```

Comment: Why not?  If you're passed an arbitrary length, what's the point of throwing?

Comment: I think the same reason `byte[] b = new byte[0]` is allowed. If its negative only then its logically impossible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a method that must return a `ByteBuffer` and returning `null` is inappropriate for whatever reason, but you have no data to return, then returning a zero-length `ByteBuffer` would satisfy those conditions.

Answer (score 2):

This can be used to implement Null Object design pattern http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern, similar to Collections.emptyList and others, creates an immutable object that can be reused.