# ByteBuffer flip when last value is null

Tags: java, bytebuffer, flip

I have a method that is supposed to return a ByteBuffer. The meat of the method does the following:

```
if (true) {
    //code that puts some data into ByteBuffer bb
    return bb
}
else {
    //should not be writing any data to bb 
    //intention: leave bb as is
    return null;
}
```

After calling this method and putting the necessary data into the ByteBuffer, I turn it into a byte array by first calling `bb.flip()`. However, if the last iteration through the if-else loop happened to be false, the last data inputted was `null` and I get the `java.lang.NullPointerException` error.

[Allocating zero capacity ByteBuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18223481/allocating-zero-capacity-bytebuffer)

According to the page above, I'm supposed to return a zero-length ByteBuffer, but I'm not sure how to return something like that.

Any ideas on how to return an empty byte buffer?

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) The answer, *"A lot. An absurd amount. More than you think you are capable of. After you have reached the end of your rope and the pain of not having the answer exceeds the vast amount of shame received by posting your question, that's when you can go ahead and ask. Because at that point, you will have done whatever research necessary to make it a good question worth asking."*

Comment: The question you posted has the exact code you need. **It is literally the second line in the question!** Every [tag:java] question you have asked so far is explained by simply reading the [tag:javadoc].

Comment: Learn to use the [JavaDoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11747712/where-is-the-javadoc-for-my-installed-java-i-have-sdk-for-7) before coming here to ask someone else to read it to you. [`ByteBuffer.allocate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#allocate(int))

Comment: I really wonder what about `capacity` - *The new buffer's capacity, in bytes* is not in *"laymans"* terms? Combined with passing `0` does not scream *zero-length ByteBuffer,*?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're going to use the ByteBuffer in either case, the method should just unconditionally return it -- returning null just leads to the error you observed.

To make this code clearer, I would just make the method return type `void`. The method can add bytes into the ByteBuffer (or not) by calling methods on it -- the return value here is actually superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

In else block use following statement  to avoid NPE(null pointer exception)

return ByteBuffer.allocate(0);